# Calf pain / tightens

Tags: running, pain, calf

When i do a long run (4 miles) or tempo run, I will get a sharp pain suddenly causing me to slow down to a walk. I will then proceed to ice when I get back home. Any ideas what it might be.

Comment: Please talk to a professional, this site is not for giving or substituting medical advice, check out the [FAQ]. Additionally your question is far too vague to be answered.

Comment: How frequently do you stretch (quads,calves,hams,etc)? Do you stretch and/or warmup before going on runs? Has this been a recurring thing or something that only recently started?

Comment: @Andre at least describe where this pain is. In the feet, in your hips, belly area (side stitches) or even in the upper body or neck? At the moment this question forces people to play the guessing game.

Comment: You definitely need to see a doctor about sharp pains you have while exercising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with others you should ask a medical professional if it continues to cause pain.

My advice is not professional, but do you think this might be a calf cramp? This can be caused by lack of vitamins, including phosphorus, magnesium, calcium, sodium and potassium. However, it seems that potassium can be the most important vitamin to prevent cramping. I used to get sharp pains in my calves when deficient in potassium. Foods high in potassium include avocados, bananas, dried apricots, mushrooms, spinach, and salmon, among many others.

Happy running!